# Android Here Map I want to customise the navigation arrow

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, heremaps

I want to customise the navigation arrow which is showing in navigation is start.Please can some one help me to customise the navigation arrow i m using here map 4.15 lib version .

I try adding marker on each latitude and longitude change but the camera animation and arrow moving forward animation is not working properly.